# what's the runtime equivalent of c# 'bracketed' type cast

Tags: c#, casting, enums, runtime

suppose I have an enum

```
[Flags]
public enum E { 
    zero = 0,
    one = 1
}
```

then I can write

```
E e;
object o = 1;
e = (E) o;
```

and it will work.

BUT if I try to do that at runtime, like

```
(o as IConvertible).ToType(typeof(E), null)
```

it will throw InvalidCastException.

So, is there something that I can invoke at runtime, and it will convert from int32 to enum, in the same way as if I wrote a cast as above?

Comment: meta - Since this Q only deals with enums suggest someone add 'enum' to the title and/or tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
object o = 1;
object z = Enum.ToObject(typeof(E), o);
```

Answer (score 0):

How does the variable look like that you save the result of that conversion in? I.e. with which type do you declare it?

If you want to have an object variable, make it so. Instead of `null`, use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create a default instance of the enum:

```
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(E));
```

Comment: I want it to be Object. That is, boxed enum. The point is that the type is not known at compile time, so I don't want to declare a 'destination' variable with exact type.

Comment: I see your problem now. It hasn't actually got anything to do with casting, as my code shows. Rather, the problem is the creation of an  instance based on a runtime type.

Comment: No. The problem hasn't got anything with object creation. I have integer value, which comes from, say, xml file. The problem is:
how do I assign it to that object? (again, the actual type E is coming as a Type parameter and is not known at compile type, so I can't write  a cast)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(E), (int)o)
```