# How to cast an object programmatically at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, casting

Suppose I have a custom control like:

```
MyControl : Control
```

if I have code like this:

```
List<Control> list = new ...
list.Add (myControl);

RolloutAnimation anim = list[0];
```

I know I can do it at compile time but I wanna do it at runtime and access MyControl specific functionality.

Comment: Why do you want to do it at runtime? If you have more types of Controls in your List, that have some specific functionality, but different types, perhaps they should implement a common interface.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think that's a better way?

Comment: I've added it as an answer, I do believe that it's a better way than verifying for multiple types by casting multiple times. With an interface, you only have to make sure your Control classes implement it, and then you only have to add everything as instances of your interface, the functions inside will be accessible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you want to do it at runtime? If you have more types of Controls in your List, that have some specific functionality, but different types, perhaps they should implement a common interface:

```
interface MyControlInterface
{
    void MyControlMethod();
}

class MyControl : Control, MyControlInterface
{
    // Explicit interface member implementation:
    void MyControlInterface.MyControlMethod()
    {
        // Method implementation.
    }
}

class MyOtherControl : Control, MyControlInterface
{
    // Explicit interface member implementation:
    void MyControlInterface.MyControlMethod()
    {
        // Method implementation.
    }
}


.....

//Two instances of two Control classes, both implementing MyControlInterface
MyControlInterface myControl = new MyControl();
MyControlInterface myOtherControl = new MyOtherControl();

//Declare the list as List<MyControlInterface>
List<MyControlInterface> list = new List<MyControlInterface>();
//Add both controls
list.Add (myControl);
list.Add (myOtherControl);

//You can call the method on both of them without casting
list[0].MyControlMethod();
list[1].MyControlMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks but in this case what type should I use for the List? Control or Interface?

Comment: The list is `List<MyControlInterface>`, so that every control you would add to it is supposed to be an instance of a class implementing `MyControlInterface`. This way, you do not care what the actual class is, just that it implements the interface, and the method you want to call is accessible.

Answer (score 4):

```
((MyControl)list[0]).SomeFunction()
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to do it at runtime, like list[0].Cast(list[0].GetType()), etc.

Comment: I think you might be confused about what "run time" means.  It means "while the program is being executed".

Comment: I mean something like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345506/whats-the-runtime-equivalent-of-c-bracketed-type-cast

Comment: I think I understand now.  The thing I wasn't getting (and I got from Luvieere's answer) is that you don't know what type you'll be casting to at run time.  But the actual casting operation happens at run time, regardless.

Answer (score 1):

`(MyControl)list[0]` will return an object of type MyControl, or throw error if list[0] is not a MyControl.

`list[0] as MyControl` will return an object of type MyControl, or null if list[0] is not of type MyControl

You can also check type type of list[0] testing `list[0] is MyControl`

Comment: Totally offtopic, but I always hated the as Object method. Means I get a null reference exception later all instead of where the actual error occurred (the location of the cast). It has lead to quite a few interesting bug hunts...

Comment: @Rontologist Not if it's used correctly. But is true a lot of people use it thinking it just "looks nicer" than a cast, and that brings trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyControl my_ctrl = list[0] as MyControl;

if(my_ctrl != null)
{
  my_ctrl.SomeFunction();
}

// Or

if(list[0] is MyControl)
{
  ((MyControl)list[0]).SomeFunction();
}
```