# Different types in an array, how to know what to cast them to when taking them out of array?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, network-programming

Assume a generic **List** of type **Packet**, holding custom classes extending **Packet**, such as **LoginPacket** or **ChatPacket**.

Let's say I put these in a list. When I take them out, the most 'specific' type each will be is **Packet**. I want to cast these into their more specific types though, back into their original **LoginPacket** or **ChatPacket** or back into whatever their original types were.

Question: How can I do this?

Reference: [How to cast an object programmatically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829605/how-to-cast-an-object-programmatically-at-runtime)

So...it seems like if these custom classes share a common interface, it would solve the casting problem? But if so, my classes can't all share one interface. I need to build interfaces upon interfaces and classes upon classes. So...how would I do this? Sorry if this question isn't so accurate. Not sure how to articulate my exact issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* have a whole long list of if/else or a switch

```
if (item is ChatPacket)
{
    // cast
}
else if (...)
{
    // cast
}
else ...
```

However, that can become unwieldly.

You may wish to revisit your class design. By having a `List<Packet>`, you're effectively stating *you do not care about the differences between the derived children*, at least in terms of their unique APIs.

In other words, if your design is

```
class Packet { public void Foo() { } }
class ChatPacket : Packet { public void Bar() { } }
```

You're saying you only care about being able to access `Foo()`.

If you *do* care about differences, perhaps you can express those differences with polymorphism via abstract or virtual methods in the base and overriden behaviors in the children. Therefore you still have a  collection of base classes, but you still get the custom behaviors as specified by each child.

```
class Packet { public virtual void Foo() { } }
class ChatPacket : Packet { public override void Foo() { } }
```

Here, you call just call `Foo()`. No casting necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
if (myPacket is LoginPacket) {
    // Do LoginPacket stuff
}

else if (myPacket is ChatPacket) {
    // Do ChatPacket stuff
}
```

Once you know if its the right type you can cast it using the `as` keyword

```
ProcessLoginPacket(myPacket as LoginPacket);
```

Comment: Ay but, what if there are many types, and you have to do this conversion really often? Would this be a design issue?

Comment: generally speaking its better to design the classes such that you don't really care what specific type they are (if you can). For example it would be better to define a method on the base class such as DoStuff() and each subclass would override and provide its own implentation of DoStuff() and then you would just call packet.DoStuff() and depending on the packet type it will call its own DoStuff() method