# Accesing Non Inherited members, via base class

Tags: c#

I have an Abstract class called `Function` which has 2 inheriting classes (actually 6, but for example 2).

The first inheriting class will be called `Push`, the other `Lift`.

The base class will have simple methods and members like `Execute(int Distance)`, `Direction` etc..

But the child classes will have individual and unique members, for instance `Push` will have `int friction`, and `Lift` will have `int gravity` (My one is btw more complicated)

So if I have a `List< Function >`, how would I edit the `gravity` member if the object were `Lift` or  the `friction` if it were `Push`?

*Please do not say "Why not make Friction and gravity the same int, and put it in the base class."*

I was thinking that the base class could have `getData()` and `setData()`, which would take an Array and the child classes can use data in the array and handle it differently whilst being able to send different data too.

---

Turns out, my problem has a simple solution. I was only trying to allow the user to set the data of each object, and this can be accomplished with a property grid with ease. I've kept the current answer as accepted since my original problem wasn't specific enough for my solution to be relevant.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515460/different-types-in-an-array-how-to-know-what-to-cast-them-to-when-taking-them-o/6515500#6515500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you need to access specific members of the classes...you shouldn't treat them as a `List<Function>`.

That being said, you should be able to do something like (using the is/as operators):

```
foreach(var f in functions)
{
    if(f is Push) { (f as Push).Friction = 4; }
    if(f is Lift) { (f as Lift).Gravity = 4; }
}
```

Comment: Agreed.  The getData()/setData() seems error-prone - would you accidentally try to set the friction in a Lift object?

You could also try a design pattern such as the [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) that helps this polymorphic behavior...

Comment: I voted up because it is the right answer, (or it at least leads to a right answer), but I don't know if I like those 1 line if statements.

Comment: @Sam, I'm sure the one liners are for quick readability in a scrunched space. The real issue with such an approach is the OP states there are 6 derived classes, so you might have 6 such type-checkers. Say you add 7, 8, and 9. Now you have to come here in modify this method, as well, which is a violation of the *Open Closed Principle*. At any rate, I very much agree with this answer's first sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce, i know my question sounds very unsafe, but i put them all in a list, since i need to serialize them, and backwards compatabilty, Will try!!! THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

Justin Niessner's answer is correct, but If you'd rather use a getter type of implimentation, you can use properties

put the following in your base class

```
public virtual int DataItem {get; set;}
```

and then in `Push` you can override the property.  do the same for other classes

```
public virtual int DataItem
{
    get
    {
        return Friction;
    }
    set
    {
        Friction = value;
    }
}
```

that way, you can do something like

```
int frictionOrGravity = item.DataItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have an abstract function in the base class that takes in some int, and then each subclass can override it with the functionality it needs? For example:

```
class Function {
    protected abstract void SetData(int n);
}

class Push : Function {
    int Friction;

    protected override void SetData(int n) {
        this.Friction = n; 
    }
}

class Lift : Function {
    int Gravity;

    protected override void SetData(int n) {
        this.Gravity= n; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest further considering your design, which sounds flawed at this point. If the properties `Friction` and `Gravity` are unrelated members of derived classes then it is difficult to understand why you would be dealing with them together.

Perhaps what you need is a new method in your base class, let's call it `Update()`. Then, both `Push` and `Lift` can implement the `Update()` method respectively to do whatever needs doing to their respective data members.

Now, you can simply call `Update()` on each `Function` object:

```
List<Function> functions;
// ...

foreach (Function f in functions)
{
    f.Update();
}
```

Comment: Your right i'll redesign it, I seem to be making some big mistakes since i don't know how else to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you could also refactor the client code to use Generics, if you could do so. 
either as a field/property: List Functions {get;set;}
or in a method: List GetFunction()